Relinking tables from MS-Access to MS-Access is suddenly extreme slow
Since years I copy files from an Access database with front-end and back-end from a customer.
On the customer network the BE file is on a server. On my PC both BE and FE files are local in the same directory.
Until recently I copied the files from my customer, opened the Linked Table Manager, and I relinked the files from the (on my PC) not existing server connection to the local file. I did this for years and it always was done in less than a minute.
Now, since a couple of months, when I do the same, it takes maybe one hour until all tables are linked again. These are maybe 20 tables. Access shows "not responding". But finally, the tables are linked correctly.
When I do this in my customer's office, it still takes less than a minute, on an Access version which is not the newest (sorry, I didn't check which version). I have the newest Office 365 version, fully updated, on Windows 10.
The database files are not corrupt, my PC is fast and has enough resources, the task manager shows almost no use of any resources.
I also tried to disconnect from any LAN or WLAN to test if this makes any difference. No difference. It still takes forever.
Does anybody have the same experience and a solution or workaround?
